# Email address flows over into second line in text input field

Tags: html, css

A user of my application has sent this mind-boggling screenshot in:

[image]

In Google Chrome on Windows, he enters a long email into the field and the text flows over into a second line underneath the input field. I am unable to recreate this in every browser on Mac and Windows. I have tried both typing and pasting the email.

The input field is simple:

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required autocomplete="email">
```

Does someone know how this happens and how to prevent it? It is as if he has a text-wrap property on the input field somehow, which, after 9 years building websites, I have thought impossible until now.

Comment: Without seeing CSS this is impossible to answer. Furthermore the input element may have been transformed into something that resembles a textbox but really isn't. Does right-click "Inspect" inside the Browser on the element show it as an input element or as something else?

Comment: @PeterB It shows as an input element. There is no CSS for inputs except Bootstrap's defaults. And I can't recreate it in any browser or device.

Comment: are you using any browser addon that might change the css of the input? I.E last pass

Comment: Well, not on my end. Maybe the user does. Essentially, I need a way to make the inpiut addon-proof, if there is such a thing.

Comment: that can't be possible. input-fields don't overflow. I tried over and over to re-produce the problem and I couldn't do that.

Comment: And yet here it is on the screenshot.